# How does `${!path//:/$'\n'}` perform parameter expansion to display $PATH with directories separated by newlines?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, debian, shell

I have trouble understanding how `${!path//:/$'\n'}` works in the shell function below.

I have looked in `man bash` and considered the use of `${parameter/pattern/string}` to subsitute `:` with `\n`, but in this case the expansion begins with `${!`? Also, why is two forward slashes used in `path//` instead of a single?

```
pathprint () {
   if (($# == 0)); then
      set -- PATH
   fi
   for path; do
      echo "$path"
      echo "${!path//:/$'\n'}"
   done
}
```

Finally, why doesn't the following "simplification" work?

```
pathprint () {
      echo "PATH"
      echo "${!PATH//:/$'\n'}"
   done
}
```

In this case, `$PATH` is expanded before parameter expansion, and `bash` complains that no parameter exists with the name of the current value of `$PATH`?

Comment: The correct simplification would be `echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"`, no exclamation mark (see choroba’s answer to understand why).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for path; do` doesn't specify the `in`, which means it iterates over the positional parameters. If you don't specify any when calling the function, $# will be zero and $1 will be set to the string `PATH`.

`${!path}` expands to the content of the variable whose name is in `$path`. It means, the parameter(s) to the function is not the path but the name of the variable(s) containing paths you want to print.

When using `//` instead of `/` in substitution, all occurrences of the pattern are replaced. Single slash only replaces the first occurrence.

Comment: I have never seen `!` used in parameter expansion before? Is it a mixture of different parameter expansions (i.e the one that does substitution and one of the `${!` ones? Where is `!` documented?

Comment: @Shuzheng: Both `!` and `/` are described in `man bash` under Parameter Expansion.